# How to run the setState() after executing insert or delete of the moor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-moor

if you touch the heart icon, I want to insert or delete the product class in the Moor database and change the heart icon to setState()

Insertion or deletion is well executed, but the heart icon does not seem to change because setState() has already been executed during insertion or deletion.

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know if my method is wrong or if there's a better way than using a "stream builder."

Thank you for reading my question.

```
Widget setFavorite() {
ProductsDao productsDao = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context).productsDao;
return StreamBuilder<List<mf.QueryRow>>(
  stream: productsDao
      .customSelect(
          "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE firestoreid LIKE '${widget.product.firestoreid}'")
      .watch(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<mf.QueryRow>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      print(snapshot.error);
      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text("");
      default:
        return Positioned(
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      snapshot.data.isEmpty
                          ? productsDao.insertProduct(this.widget.product)
                          : productsDao.deleteProduct(this.widget.product);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    snapshot.data.isEmpty
                        ? Icons.favorite_border
                        : Icons.favorite,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have the method of inserting, but if you are using provider you need to use a function that will update a state and uses notifiyListeners().
When you are using notify listeners you don't even need setstate it will update all the values.

```
class AppDatabase extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  ProductsDao _productsDao;
  
  ProductsDao get productsDao => _productsDao;
  
  void insertProduct(value){
     this._productsDao.insertProduct(value);
        notifiyListeners();
      }

void deleteProduct(value){
    this._productsDao.deleteProduct(value);
    notifiyListeners();
  }

    }
```

Now you should use the provider insertProduct to refresh the state of your value.

```
Widget setFavorite() {
AppDatabase appState = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context);
return StreamBuilder<List<mf.QueryRow>>(
  stream: appState.productsDao
      .customSelect(
          "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE firestoreid LIKE '${widget.product.firestoreid}'")
      .watch(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<mf.QueryRow>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      print(snapshot.error);
      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text("");
      default:
        return Positioned(
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      snapshot.data.isEmpty
                          ? appState.insertProduct(this.widget.product)
                          : appState.deleteProduct(this.widget.product);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    snapshot.data.isEmpty
                        ? Icons.favorite_border
                        : Icons.favorite,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  },
);
```

This will refresh your value in the ui.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Provider was used to access productDao class in the moor database. There is no other action

Comment: You should create a method inside the appdatabase that will get the insert with the new value and will insert it in the list you have and then call the notifiyListeners.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code that will make you to refresh the ui. You must use your provider to refresh it and not the ProductsDao object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait for the database to finish using await :

```
          onTap: () async {
              snapshot.data.isEmpty
                  ? await productsDao.insertProduct(this.widget.product)
                  : await productsDao.deleteProduct(this.widget.product);
            setState(() {}
            });
          },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, the icon still does not change. Is there another way?

Comment: Maybe you should use a state managment plugin.
I use MobX, when updating my Moor database I call a MobX function and MobX, verify the value, store it and change it on the UI